# Using memoized callbacks in React, when also creating multiple components with .map

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What's the right way to create a memoized callback for use in components that have been created from a `.map` function?

ie. Here's a non-memoized version of what I want to achieve:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const NUM_BUTTONS = 5;

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Value is : {value}</h1>

      {new Array(NUM_BUTTONS).fill(true).map((v, i) => (
        <button key={i} onClick={() => setValue(i)}>
          {i}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[(Code Sandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-galois-0k775)

Simple enough.

Now the problem is - I have that inline function which will cause those `<button>` components to re-render each time this component renders.

One approach I thought of, is to create a list of memoized callbacks, and map over them:

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const callBacks = new Array(NUM_BUTTONS).fill(true).map((v, i) => {
    return React.useCallback(() => setValue(i), []);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Value is : {value}</h1>

      {callBacks.map((v, i) => (
        <button key={i} onClick={v}>
          i
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[(Code Sandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-borg-cdrnk).

But of course - this breaks one of the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), you can't call a hook from inside a function or a conditional. Curiously enough, this code still works though.

The alternative I've got, is create a separate `<SetValueButton>` component that has the value bound to it, like so:

```
function SetValueButton(props) {
  const { value, onClick } = props;
  const handleClick = React.useCallback(() => onClick(value), [onClick, value]); 

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>{value}</button>;
}

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const setValueCb = React.useCallback(i => setValue(i), []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Value is : {value}</h1>

      {new Array(NUM_BUTTONS).fill(true).map((v, i) => (
        <SetValueButton key = {i} onClick={setValueCb} value={i} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[(Code Sandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-mendeleev-vfhp6)

Is this the right idea, or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: but is it really neccessary? typically extra re-render goes literally in seconds if not cause DOM reflow. Using any approach(like passing data attribute, extracting interm component or any tricks with `useRef`) affects code readability/maintainability in bad way.

Comment: @skyboyer - This is just an example. What if for example, I had a grid of a thousand individually clickable grid items?

Comment: still see no issue with extra re-render(without reflow). motivation speech: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-slow-render-before-you-fix-the-re-render/

Answer (score 4):

The best way to avoid using an inline arrow function here without creating multiple functions is to make use of `data-attribute`

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const NUM_BUTTONS = 5;

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const handleClick = React.useCallback((event) => {
      const id = event.target.getAttribute('data-index');
      setValue(id);
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Value is : {value}</h1>

      {new Array(NUM_BUTTONS).fill(true).map((v, i) => (
        <button key={i} data-index={i} onClick={handleClick}>
          {i}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sky-u7txk)**

Comment: @dwjohnston, does the above answer help you?

Comment: Do you really need to use React.useCallback here?

Comment: @Tom, No it isn't necessary to use `useCallback` here but it gives you an added optimisation in cases where you pass on the function to the child components which are either memoized or pure components

Comment: Hmm, I don't follow. Since the function is the same function passed down to child components, shouldn't memoized or pure components not re-render? I don't see why you need useCallback for that?

Comment: @Tom the `<button>` component would re-render every time `App` does because we are defining a new version `handleClick` each render. Using `useCallback` memoises the `handleClick` so that `button` receives identical props and can skip rerendering.